# Rails - Submit form to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I have ProjectsController and i added there a method called search_for_members i want this method to update a div with members names when the user hit submit via ajax the problem here is that i'm getting routing error

> No route matches [POST] "/projects/47"

Any help?

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
     resources :user_stories
     get '/projects/:project_id/searchformembers' => 'projects#searchformembers'
  end
```

views/projects/show

```
      <%= form_tag :url => {:action => "search_for_members"} , :method => 'get', :remote => true do%>
         <div>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'User name'%>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag "Add user", :name => nil, :class => "btn btn-info"%>
      <% end%>

      <div id="members">
        <%= render @users %> 
      <% end %>
```

projects_controller

```
 def search_for_members
   if (params[:search])
     @users = User.search(params[:search],   @project).page(params[:page]).per_page(4) 
  else 
     @users = @project.users
  end    
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
  end 
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route definition is wrong and does not match to your controller or `form_for` usage. Change your route like this:

```
resources :projects do
  get :search_for_members, :on => :member
end
```

And then update your `form_for` definition in your view like this:

```
  <%= form_tag search_for_members_project_path(@project), :method => 'get', :remote => true do%>
```

And you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i'm still getting this routing error.

Comment: Check my update and read ``form_tag`` reference http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag